# Generating CRUD with entity framework (like DataSets can)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, dataset

I added am edmx file and a table to my project.  How can I get it to generate CRUD operations?   I did this in the past where it generated them as stored procs, but cant find the option on the table properties.  What did I do wrong?

**UPDATE**
After fiddling about, I discovered I am confusing my tools.  With a `DataSet.xsd` I can drag a table onto the Dataset Designer and click the *TableName*TableAdapter.  If you view the properties window you will see "DeleteCommand, InsertCommand, SelectCommand, UpdateCommand".  Is there a way to accomplish this task with Entity Framework too?

(If you have any trouble seeing this you can right click the table in dataset designer > Configure > Advanced options > check "Generate Insert, Update and Delete statements".

Comment: What do you mean by "generating" CRUD operations? EF will only create derived context which can be used to execute CRUD operations.

Comment: Maybe I am getting my tools confused.  There was a tool, thought it was entity, that when one went to properties for a table/entity it had the CRUD statements (select value1, value2) that you could edit.  This way I didn't need to create 4 stored procedures by hand.  Since the entity framework is already aware of the schema it sure doesn't seem like a big leap to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has responded with a method to accomplish the task, then I have to assume the functionality does not exist.